# Calling multiple parallel call to SOAP services using spring boot # SOAP Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, soap, soap-client

I am currently using spring boot. I have a list of request objects (around 1000) and would like to call SOAP services in parallel for all the objects and get the response for all of them. Once all the request is processed, I want to execute my program in parallel.

Any good recommendations?

```java
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    @Autowired
    private SOAPConnector connector;

    public void getEmployeeData(){
    List<Request> lstRequest = [List of Objects];
    List<Response> lstResponse = new ArrayList();
    for(int i=0 ; i <=lstRequest.size()-1; i++)
    {       
        lstResponse.add(connector.callEmployeeService());
    }   
        callAnotherMethod(lstResponse);
    }
}


public class SOAPConnector extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public Response callEmployeeService(Request request) {        
        try{
            return (Response) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {            

        }
    }
}


@Configuration
public class Configurator {

    @Value("${service.url}")
    private String SERVICE_URL;

    @Autowired
    ComponentMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender;

    @Bean
    public SOAPConnector getClient() {
        SOAPConnector client = new SOAPConnector();
        client.setMarshaller(getMarshaller());
        client.setUnmarshaller(getMarshaller());
        client.setDefaultUri(SERVICE_URL);

        try {
            client.setMessageSender(httpComponentsMessageSender.getHttpComponentsMessageSender());

        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("error on message sender ");
        }

        return client;
    }

    private Jaxb2Marshaller getMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Request.class, Response.class);
        return marshaller;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that this is risky, Jaxb2Marshaller is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at Java 8's `CompletableFuture`. You can have a go as follows:

```
List<Request> lstRequest = [List of Objects];
CompletableFuture[] futures = new CompletableFuture[lstRequest.size()];

for(int i=0 ; i <=lstRequest.length - 1; i++) {       
    futures[i] = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> connector.callEmployeeService());
}   

CompletableFuture.allOf(lstResponse).thenApply((result) -> {
    // This is where you get all of your responses
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hasan. Much appreciated. I will apply this and share you the result

Comment: Sure. The syntax might change a bit, since I wrote this without an IDE and from memory.